# How to make an anchor element cover all space inside a list item?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an anchor element cover all vertical space inside a list item. Because when I hover on a list item element, the href attribute of the anchor doesn't trigger. It triggers just if I hover on the text of the anchor element, doesn't trigger when above or below the anchor element. There is vertical space above and below of anchor element. I set margins to 0 but no effect. The schema is like this:

How the CSS should be?

```css
li {
  background: pink;
}

a {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Text</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

SCSS snippet:

```
ul {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;

        // a:not(.button) {
        //   display: inline-flex;
        // }

        li {
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          // padding: $header-nav--padding-v__mobile * 0.5 0px;
          // border-radius: 10px;

          &:hover,
          &:active {
            background-color: #ffffff13;
          }

          a {
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            display: block !important;
          }

          ul { 
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0%;
            margin: 0%;

            li:hover {
              background-color: color-bg(button-primary-hover);
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: What is "triggering the href attribute"? Have you used your browser's document inspector to see what's up? What CSS have you tried?

Comment: Could you explain a bit further what you require? For example, are you expecting the disc that indicates a new li to be hoverable?

Comment: There is problem about vertical spacing above and below the text of <a>. Even if I set all margins and padding to "0". I am trying to route by <a> element, but it doesnt cover the whole vertical space

Comment: Could you put up a snippet which shows the problem? Perhaps putting a background color on the li elements would show them more clearly. At the moment I cannot reproduce the problem you decide.

Comment: @AHaworth ok now trying. The SCSS is large but I try isolating

Comment: @AHaworth added snippet to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `width` attribute to make it fill all the space of the parent element. You will also need to set `display` to `block` so it knows to fill up the whole parent.

```css
ul {
  background: magenta;
}

li {
  background: lime;
}

.link {
  background: cyan;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://example.org" class="link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="link">second element</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To cover the vertical size, use the `height` and `padding` attributes:

I also added a different link colour on hover so the user knows what link they're hovering on.

```css
ul {
  background: magenta;
}

li {
  background: lime;
}

.link {
  background: cyan;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
}

.link:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://example.org" class="link">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="link">second element</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @ethry but still doesn't trigger, there is problem about vertical space. Even if I make margin and padding of <a> element to "0", hovering below the text doesn't trigger the click

Comment: Hovering never triggers the click.

Comment: sorry mistyped, clicking doesnt effect when the mouse is not exactly on the text I meant. Clicking above <a> element while maintaining inside <li> element does nothing

Comment: Oh, I will see if I can fix that.

Comment: I changed the answer.

Comment: now I am  looking

Comment: Ok, now solved. I added 
         li { margin: 0 !important;
          padding: 0 !important; } inside CSS. I think some of scss variables mixed and broke the css rules. I am also choosing your answer as correct since it is also correct